# AMD CPU Temperature

Tags: cpu, temperature

I installed an AMD A8-6600 and the CPU temp seems high. It's running between 60 - 68C in the bios health monitor. I'm using the onboard graphics. That temperature seems too high to me. Is that temp above normal when using onboard graphics with that CPU?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After resetting the BIOS to defaults, I started disabling options one at a time. The temperature stopped spiking after I disabled "AMD Turbo Core Technology". Not sure why Turbo Core spiked the temperature, but the temp immediately dropped back down to a normal range when I disabled it.

Comment: Well that’s because it “overclocks” the CPU, naturally. Within limits of what’s energetically (input power, temperature) feasible, of course.

Comment: Seems silly/unnecessary for it to OC the CPU in such a way while sitting in the BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

Have you made sure that you seated the CPU cooler/fan properly, and also that you used enough TIM (Thermal paste)?

If the cooler isn't seated properly then there could be a gap between the CPU and the cooler, which could cause tempteratures to be higher than usual.

Comment: I installed the stock cooler with the thermal paste already applied. The temp spiked up very quickly and sort of stabilized above 60C

Comment: Ok, have you made sure that the CPU fan is plugged in as well? Have you tried running a game to see what sort of temperatures your getting?

Comment: I don't want to install an OS until I get the temperature sorted out. The fan is spinning on the Cooler. I should be shooting for around 40 - 50C right?

Comment: Yeah that's probably an OK temperature. Possibly a bit lower but it's the stock cooler after all. Have you overclocked the CPU at all?

Comment: No, unless the BIOS had some OC clocking already set. I'm going to put in a dedicated graphics card and reset the BIOS to defaults to make sure.